# Time Limit Exceeded : As far from land as possible

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I was doing leetcode problem [As far from land as possible](https://leetcode.com/problems/as-far-from-land-as-possible/description/).
Here is the code I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
class Solution:
    def maxDistance(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        counter = 0
        n = len(grid)

        
        while grid.count(1) != n*n:
            dp=np.zeros((n,n))
            print(dp)
            for i in range(n):
                for j in range(n):
                    if grid[i][j] == 1 and not dp[i][j]:
                        if i-1 > 0:
                            grid[i-1][j] = 1
                            dp[i-1][j] = 1
                        if i+1 < n:
                            grid[i+1][j] = 1
                            dp[i+1][j] = 1
                        if j-1 > 0:
                            grid[i][j-1] = 1
                            dp[i][j-1] = 1
                        if j+1 < n:
                            grid[i][j+1] = 1
                            dp[i][j+1] = 1
                        dp[i][j]=1
            counter+=1
            print(grid)
            print("\n")
            print(dp)
        
        return counter
```

It is giving TLE and on debugging I found that that the `grid` and `dp` are not changing after first iteration. I am unable to understand the reason why it is happening. Thank you in advance!

I was expecting all the elements of the `grid` array to become one and that is the terminating condition for the `while` loop. The `dp` array is to keep track of the 1, we have put in so that we can skip it later and it is recreated every-time so that we can iterate again. for the first time, it works fine but after that the program runs in an infinite loop.

Comment: You're re-creating and initializing `dp=np.zeros((n,n))` on every iteration of your while loop.

Comment: Since your `grid` is a list of lists, `grid.count(1)` only looks at the sub-list but not each element, so it'll always count 0, so you never exit your while loop.

Comment: does this pass test cases?